# select rows based on multiple criteria in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a huge dataset similar to the one below:

```
Df <- data.frame("Candidate ID"   = c(1042,  1042, 1113, 1113, 1146, 1277, 1381, 1381, 1402, 1402),
                 "Application ID" = c(1040, 13006, 1111, 1125, 1144, 1274,   41,   61,   64,   65),
                  "Question"     = c("Yes", "Yes", "No","Yes", "Yes","No", "No", "No","Yes", "No"))
```

Background: Candidates can apply to multiple job requisitions and receive each time a different application id. One candidate id can also apply to up to 25 job requisitions, i.e. apply 25 different times. In my simplified example, the maximum is two.

[image: data]

I would like to extract all candidate ids where the answers to the question are all "yes".
In the example, I would like to extract only the candidate ids 1042 and 1146. How can I do this in R?

I checked in StackOverflow and could not find a matching answer, perhaps also to difficulties in describing the problem. At least I made an effort in creating a minimum reproducible example to make it easy to help me.

Comment: A couple posts that should help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31661704/5325862 https://stackoverflow.com/q/55012776/5325862 It is a difficult problem to search for, but the base `any` or `all` functions should be useful

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. It was the first time for me to write a reproducible example and to receive so many useful replies.

Answer (score 4):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
Df %>% group_by(Candidate.ID) %>% filter(all(Question == 'Yes'))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   Candidate.ID [2]
  Candidate.ID Application.ID Question
         <dbl>          <dbl> <chr>   
1         1042           1040 Yes     
2         1042          13006 Yes     
3         1146           1144 Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

An option in `base R` with [`subset`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/subset)

1. Extract the 'Candidate.ID' where 'Question' value "Yes"
2. Extract the 'Candidate.ID' where 'Question' value is "No"
3. Get the `unique` 'Candidate.ID' that have 'Yes' value in 'Question' and not any 'No' by doing the `setdiff` from 1 and 2
4. Use that 'Candidate.ID' to create a logical vector using `%in%` with the whole column of 'Candidate.ID' for `subset`tting rows with 'Candidate.ID' having only 'Yes' value in 'Question'

```
subset(Df, Candidate.ID %in% setdiff(Candidate.ID[Question == 'Yes'], 
       Candidate.ID[Question == "No"]))
#  Candidate.ID Application.ID Question
#1         1042           1040      Yes
#2         1042          13006      Yes
#5         1146           1144      Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

**data.table**

```r
df <- data.frame("Candidate ID"   = c(1042,  1042, 1113, 1113, 1146, 1277, 1381, 1381, 1402, 1402),
                 "Application ID" = c(1040, 13006, 1111, 1125, 1144, 1274,   41,   61,   64,   65),
                 "Question"     = c("Yes", "Yes", "No","Yes", "Yes","No", "No", "No","Yes", "No"))



library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[all(Question == "Yes")], by = Candidate.ID]
#>    Candidate.ID Application.ID Question
#> 1:         1042           1040      Yes
#> 2:         1042          13006      Yes
#> 3:         1146           1144      Yes
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>